# How do I adjust and debug for this error in my Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, try-catch

I am just learning this, so bear with me please.
I'm receiving the error below when I run my Python script:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/duckwalkin/PycharmProjects/threxx/washOut2.py
08-06-2021_13-29-28
this is:  2021-08-06-04:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/duckwalkin/PycharmProjects/threxx/washOut2.py", line 132, in <module>
    call_parse_json()
  File "/Users/duckwalkin/PycharmProjects/threxx/washOut2.py", line 100, in call_parse_json
    mainList.extend(parse_json(main_request(baseurl, x, endpoint, headers)))
  File "/Users/duckwalkin/PycharmProjects/threxx/washOut2.py", line 68, in parse_json
    for item in response['_embedded']['results']:
KeyError: '_embedded'
```

I'm pulling data from a provided api, there are approx. 10k of records in this api, and I need all the records

**the json data looks like the snippet below:**

```
"_embedded": {
        "results": [
            {
                "isCanceled": false,
                "_rallyScore": 0,
                "_type": "opportunity",
                "publishDate": "2021-08-04T20:29:02-04:00",
                "isActive": true,
                "title": "TomCats rule",
                "type": {
                    "code": "a1-2",
                    "value": "West Chester"
                },
                "descriptions": [
```

**the script runs for a few minutes then dies with the above noted error.**

If I make a smaller for-loop, 25 pages **v**s the total of 400 pages (25 items per page), **the script runs flawlessly** - It dumps my data into a .csv file using to_csv(), then to.sql() into my db.

I was amazed that I got this thing working, up until I ran it on the entire api

for obvious reasons of course, I can't show the entire code, but I am importing the following libraries, pulling the api, looping through the pages, dumping the data into .csv and then in to a mysql db.  I am pulling the data via a url and looping through the pages by updating the page variable i.e. (page_1, page_2, page_3, etc.)

```
import requests
            import json
            import pandas as pd
            import sqlalchemy as sq
            import time
            from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

**so obviously something is up with the KEY**,

1. what are the best methods for debugging this to find the point of
   contention?
2. then, since this is not my api, how can I use a try/catch to just continue to the next record.

I want this script to run each night/noon (already have this setup), but should it encounter this problem, i just want it to skip that record and move to the next.

Thanks in advance for your insights and/or suggestions.

Comment: in `washout2.py` at line 67.5 do `if not response.get("_embedded"): print(response)`. This will show you the response that lacks this key. I'm going to guess that is because `response.ok` is false and you have some sort of server error (503 is my guess)

Comment: ***here is something:***
                ```{'timestamp': '2021-08-06T18:46:15.395+0000', 'path': None, 'status': 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 'message': 'Internal Server Error', 'error': 'Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]'}```

```def parse_json(response):
    animalList = []
    if not response.get("_embedded"):
        print(response)
    for item in response['_embedded']['results']:
        animal_details = {```

server error as u said.  What should I do, how to address?  Did server connection time out?  My server or theirs?

Comment: Well, quick and dirty thing would be in your loop/paging after you do a request check `response.ok` and if it is not true then wait 30 seconds and try again or just skip to the next page.  It is a little hard to say without seeing more of your code

Comment: I have been investigating, so got the details on internal server error, so think it is because i am trying to pull everything at once.  going to figure out how to pull the items on 1k increments and see that works.  Thanks so much, sometimes just being pointed in the right direction helps so much.